# Drawing multiple chart Amchart using different data providers

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to draw multiple linear chart, I am using a socket.io connection to receive multiple Data (MQTT messages) from different sensors. The problem is that I cannot find a way to reuse the code for every chart, this is what I have so far:

```
var socket = io();

var chartData = [];
chart_config = {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "fontFamily": "sans-serif",
  "fontSize" : "12",
  "valueAxes": [{
    "id": "v1",
    "position": "left"
  }],
  "mouseWheelZoomEnabled": true,
  "graphs": [{
    "id": "g1",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
    "hideBulletsCount": 50,
    "valueField": "value",
    "balloonText": "[[value]]",
    "balloon":{
      "drop":true
    }
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
   "limitToGraph":"g1"
  },
  "categoryField": "date",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "equalSpacing": true,
    "dashLength": 1,
    "minorGridEnabled": true
  },
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "export": {
          "enabled": true
  }
};


var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("V1_chart", chart_config);



socket.on('panel1_V', function (data) {
  var newDate = new Date();
  chartData.push({
    date: newDate,
    value: data.message
  });
  console.log('mqtt message: ' + data.message);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(chartData));
  if (chartData.length > 20) {
    chartData.splice(0, chartData.length - 20);
  }
  chart.validateData();
});
```

thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Are you having problem in creating multiple charts with the same configuration object?

Comment: Yes, I want to recycle as much code as possible, but it seems to be very hard to achieve , tried to use the same chart_config but generete a lot of problems, the only way I got to get it working, is creating multiple objets each with its chart_config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do a deep clone of the configuration object for every chart, keep the original unused.

The code below is an example how to clone the object in case you don't have a helper to do it.

```
/**
 * Define function for cloning objects
 * Taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object
 */
function clone(obj) {
var copy;

// Handle the 3 simple types, and null or undefined
if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;

// Handle Date
if (obj instanceof Date) {
    copy = new Date();
    copy.setTime(obj.getTime());
    return copy;
}

// Handle Array
if (obj instanceof Array) {
    copy = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
    copy[i] = clone(obj[i]);
    }
    return copy;
}

// Handle Object
if (obj instanceof Object) {
    copy = {};
    for (var attr in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = clone(obj[attr]);
    }
    return copy;
}

throw new Error("Unable to copy obj! Its type isn't supported.");
}

/**
 * Create first chart
 */

// create a copy of the universal config
var chartConfig1 = clone(chartConfig);
```

Please check this example: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/reusing-the-same-config-object-for-multiple-charts/